# How to overcome problem with regex flag settings (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

I use the following code for multiple replace words in string:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in abbreviationsDict().keys()) + r')\W', flags=re.I)
        s = pattern.sub(lambda x: abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1)] + ' ', s)
```

The function with dictionary is:

```
def abbreviationsDict():
    return {'ref.': 'reference', 'ref:': 'reference', 'approx.': 'approximately', 'no.': '', 'nos.': ''}
```

And for the sentence `s = "Variation of Condition on planning application Ref: CB/15/03633/FULL dated 30/11/2015: Condition 9"` I get an error :

```
   s = pattern.sub(lambda x: abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1)] + ' ', s)

KeyError: 'Ref:'
```

It works when I lowercase `s` variable but I get lowercase results. What I'm doing wrong with this flag so it's doesn't work as needed?

Comment: Hi! I'm not able to reproduce your problem, since in the `pattern.sub` line you are referencing the undefined variable `s` at the end of the method. Also, is there any reason not to use a variable `abbreviationsDict` instead of a function?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a function or variable. I've assigned "s".

Comment: `lambda x: abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1).lower()] + ' '`

Comment: I also [suggest a pattern improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55388379/3832970), as replacing any non-word char with a space does not look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys in the dictionary are lowercase you should turn the matches to lower case:

```
s = pattern.sub(lambda x: abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1).lower()] + ' ', s)
                                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gJYqRJ):

```
import re
def abbreviationsDict():
    return {'ref.': 'reference', 'ref:': 'reference', 'approx.': 'approximately', 'no.': '', 'nos.': ''}
pattern = re.compile(r'\b({})(?!\w)'.format('|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in abbreviationsDict().keys())), flags=re.I)
s = "Variation of Condition on planning application Ref: CB/15/03633/FULL dated 30/11/2015: Condition 9"
s = pattern.sub(lambda x: abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1).lower()], s)
print(s)
# => Variation of Condition on planning application reference CB/15/03633/FULL dated 30/11/2015: Condition 9
```

Note that the `\W` at the end of your pattern consumed any non-word char and you replaced it with a space. I suggest turning `\W` into a `(?!\w)` *unambiguous trailing word boundary* and discard appending `" "` in the lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks for these corrections it's really helpful. That's what I wanted to avoid lowercase the output.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `re.I` to make your parser case insensitive, the matches of your regex are returned with the original case. Thus, you will need to change

```
abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1)]
```

to

```
abbreviationsDict()[x.group(1).lower()]
```